# Azure DevOps: Publishing a file created on a previous task wont work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My pipeline looks like this:

```
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: "Create Excel sheet"
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      failOnStderr: false
      scriptPath: /create_excel.py

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: '_buildOutput/**'
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

And the last line of the python code that it runs looks like this, it returns an excel sheet:

```
def create_excel():
        ...
        return rn_df.to_excel(fr'rn{rel_ver}.xlsx', sheet_name=f"RN {rel_ver}", index=False)
```

But I see nothing is copied nor uploaded. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the YAML sample, the default working directory of the python task is `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`.

When the task runs the python file, it will create the excel sheet in the working directory.

To solve this issue, you can change the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` to `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` in the next tasks.

For example:

```
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: "Create Excel sheet"
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      failOnStderr: false
      scriptPath: /create_excel.py

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: '_buildOutput/**'
      targetFolder: $(build.sourcesdirectory)

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
      artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

Comment: Thx. What is difference of using Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory vs build.sourcesdirectory? I just solved the problem other way around. Used Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory everywhere. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: You can refer to this doc: [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)They represent different paths in the agent

Comment: Another option is to change the current working directory